# BeforeSave Gorm trigger to insert field into another table if not existing

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have SQL Syntax that I need to convert to Gorm to be executed before a insertion into a table.

Executing with prepared statement isn't supported yet even after trimming out the delimiters.

Here's the statement:

```
db.Exec("CREATE TRIGGER trg_new_user BEFORE INSERT ON chats FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE phone = NEW.phone) THEN INSERT INTO users (phone) VALUES (NEW.phone); END IF; END ;")
```

Comment: Have you checked gorm hooks? https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html

But if you are trying to achieve the UPSERT like use case you can use the create-conflicts in gorm https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Upsert-x2F-On-Conflict